# Atom editor indent size spaces?

Tags: atom-editor

I am using OSX El Capitan and Atom 1.2.4. And I also have installed "tabs-to-spaces" package.

I am trying to setup the editor to indent and make the tab be 2 spaces. But I am not able to make this work, here is my setup

[image]

[image]

Thank you

Comment: Doesn't that screenshot show two space tabs? Do you mean you want that you want a tab to be a tab character? If so then you'd want to set your tab type to hard.

Comment: @BenPye sorry, you were right, thank you for your answer. I googled and here is the thing, seems that is because some languages have their own indentation rules. As I was writing Python, it indent to four spaces.

Comment: where did you find that setting to change the amount of spaces?

Comment: @CharlieParker I found in Atom -> Preferences -> Editor. I am not sure if that appeared after installing the tab-to-spaces plugin.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is funny. I also like using 2 spaces and was struggling with the described behaviour. When I put the following lines into config:

```
".python.source":
  editor:
    tabLength: 2
```

(Main Menu -> Atom -> Config...)

Atom starts using 2 spaces in my python code. But if try to change settings in language-python package, those lines simply disappear and 4 spaces indentation is back. Thankfully all other settings seem to not reset this, so if you don't mess with language-python settings page, everything should be fine.

Answer (score 4):

I answer my own question because could be useful for someone else.

Atom and the plugin are working, and are indenting 2 spaces.

But as I was writing Python code, the suggestion [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) is 4 spaces. Seems Atom is forcing 4 spaces.

Comment: Any way to force it to 2 spaces only? Hate using 4 spaces.